# Can't download file from Firebase Storage swift 4.2

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

I changed the permissions on the Firebase console and set to allow all users access without the need for an authentication.

I have the following code:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Utils.initApp()

    return true
}
```

**Utils.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class Utils
{
    static var inventoryJsonString = "Inventory/Inventory.json"
    static var oneMB : Int64 = 1024 * 1024

    static func initApp()
    {
        getJsonDate(inventoryJsonString)
    }

    static func getJsonData(filePath: String)
    {        
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        let jsonRef = storageRef.child("Inventory")

        jsonRef.getData(maxSize: self.oneMB)
        {
            extractedData, error in
            print("a")
            if let error = error{
                print("b")
        }
        else
        {
            print("c")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling that function but nothing happnes - I don't get an error, yet I'm not getting the url (also tried with `getData` and got nothing). I tripple checked the path in `filePath` and it's correct.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "I'm calling that function but nothing happnes" Please make sure the code in your question contain enough information for us to see what happens. As it stands, we have no way to know what `jsonRef` and `filePath` are (even though you don't seem to use the latter). Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, thought I included the ref line, apparently I mistakenly deleted it along with the comments. I updated the code. And as for filePath, it’s a string for the file, for example: "images/image.jpg"

Comment: That code looks fine, and should call the callback even with a non-existing path. You might want to check the log file for any relevant messages. Also: are you successfully using Firebase anywhere else in your app yet? If not, double check how you initialize it (since that is not included in the code you shared, and can be a common source of problems).

Comment: Can you add a `print(filePath)` and include what the output is in the question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - I'm not using Firebase anywhere else in my app (yet). I added the initialisation code of Firebase. Jay - I tried that, it prints nothing, when debugging I see that it doesn't stop at the breakpoints - not in the error nor when in the "valid" case.

Comment: Thinking through this *it doesn't stop at the breakpoints*... If the code doesn't stop at any breakpoints then the code is not being executed. That means the problem lies elsewhere. Also note that's not how you configure Firebase. See step #2 in the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Set Up Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start#set_up). Also note that your function `func getJsonData` is not being called in the provided code so therefore it will not execute.

Comment: @Jay - I just showed the code which calls `Firebase`, of course I'm calling that function from other areas of my code. I updated the post with the entire flow. As you can see, the function `getJsonData` is being called. When I say that the code doesn't stop at the breakpoints I mean inside the closure. The code does stop at the line `jsonRef.getData(maxSize: self.oneMB)` but then when I click to go to the next step in debug- it jumps straight to the end of the function. Meaning - it doesn't print `a` nor `b` nor `c` (in the updated post). Also know that I have the `Google plist` in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to read the actual json file, not all the files *within the Inventory path*

Here's your code with notes on how to fix:

```
class Utils
{
    static var inventoryJsonString = "Inventory/Inventory.json" //NOT USED!

    static var oneMB : Int64 = 1024 * 1024

    static func initApp() {
        getJsonDate(inventoryJsonString)
    }

    static func getJsonData(filePath: String) {  //filePath is NOT USED!    
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

        **this is a PATH to the enclosing directory only and not the JSON file**
        let enclosingPathRef = storageRef.child("Inventory")

        **add this to make it work**
        let actualFileRef = enclosingPathRef.child("Inventory.json")

        actualFileRef.getData(maxSize: self.oneMB) { extractedData, error in
           if let error = error{
              print("an error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription")
           } else {
              print("success!")
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. So just to make sure I understand correctly first I navigate to the correct path, and then I "open" the file, right? If my path is `Inventory/Images/1/1.json` then the above `enclosingPathRef` would be: `let enclosingPathRef = storageRef.child("Inventory/Images/1")` and the above `actualFileRef` would be `let actualFileRef = enclosingPathRef.child("1.json")`, right? Again - thanks a lot!

Comment: @Idanis Yes, that is correct. You can shorten the code as well. `let actualPathToFile = storageRef.child("Inventory/Images/1/1.json")` I left it verbose so you can see the pattern more clearly.

Comment: actually that's also something I tried in my trial-and-error and that didn't work, and now, your solution worked a few runs, bur suddenly it stopped working, and I'm now back where I started - using the code you suggested, but the `error` nor the `success` are being called. Maybe it has something to do with that `oneMB` parameter? Maybe there is a quota for calls and once it is reached, I'm being blocked? The behaviour of this thing is really weird.

Comment: @Idanis That code works consistently as I pulled it from a working app. Also, the end result of my above comment vs what's in the code is the same: use .getData with a specific file reference ("Inventory/Images/1/1.json"), not an enclosing directory ("Inventory"). The `self.oneMB* is fine and I use something similar in my code. If neither err no success prints, that would indicate the firebase function is not being called at all, or the ref is nil or possible something else as that's kinda a Singleton pattern so other things could interfere (Firebase not initialized for example).